# Animation jumps to 0 before starting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transforms

I'm making a coverflow image slider using jQuery animate. The first time the animation is ran it jumps to `0` instead of starting at `-500`.

Also when I move all the way to the right and it loops back the animation doesn't start at the beginning like it should. It animates from the end back to the beginning first before starting.

I've tried finding how to make the animation start at a specific value without luck.

What it should do is start the animation from the given value without jumping to `0` first. It should also loop back to the start from the current value instead of animating from the end back to the beginning.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slides_container div:first').addClass('previous_slide');
  $('.slides_container div:nth-child(2)').addClass('current_slide');
  $('.slides_container div:nth-child(3)').addClass('next_slide');
});

var options = {
  autoplay: 0000, //delay between transitions in milliseconds; 0 or lower is no autoplay
  sliderTransitionSpeed: 1200, //speed of the animation when changing slides
  transitionAnimation: '',
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (options.autoplay > 0) {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, options.autoplay);
  }
  
  if (options.transitionAnimation == 'slider') {
    jQuery('#slider').addClass('slider');
  } else if (options.transitionAnimation == 'coverflow') {
    jQuery('#slider').addClass('coverflow');
  } else {
    jQuery('#slider').addClass('slider');
  }

  var slideCount = $('#slider .slides_container div').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider .slides_container div').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider .slides_container div').height();
  var sliderContainerWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider .slides_container').css({
    transform: "translate3d(" + -slideWidth + "px, 0px, 0px)"
  });

  $('#slider .slides_container div').css("line-height", slideHeight + "px");

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider .slides_container').css({
    width: sliderContainerWidth
  });
  
  $('#slider .slides_container').css({
    "transform": "translate3d( px, 0px, 0px)"
  });
  
  // , marginLeft: - slideWidth
  // $('#slider .slides_container div:last-child').prependTo('#slider .slides_container');

  var sliderLocation = -slideWidth;
  var maxLocationRight = slideCount * -slideWidth + slideWidth;
  console.log(maxLocationRight);
  console.log(sliderLocation);

  function moveLeft() {
    sliderLocation += slideWidth;
    if (sliderLocation == 0) {
      console.log("begin");
    }
    $('#slider .slides_container').animate({
      sliderLocation
    }, {
      step: function(now, fx) {
        $(this).css({
          "transform": "translate3d(" + now + "px, 0px, 0px)"
        });
      },
      duration: options.sliderTransitionSpeed,
      complete: function() {
        console.log('Animation is done');
        console.log(sliderLocation);
      }
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    if (sliderLocation == maxLocationRight) {
      $('#slider .slides_container').css({
        transform: "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"
      });
      sliderLocation = 0;

      console.log(sliderLocation);
      console.log("end");
    } else {
      console.log("moveRight");
      sliderLocation -= slideWidth;

      $('#slider .slides_container').animate({
        sliderLocation
      }, {
        step: function(now, fx) {
          $(this).css({
            "transform": "translate3d(" + now + "px, 0px, 0px)"
          });
        },
        duration: options.sliderTransitionSpeed,
        complete: function() {
          console.log('Animation is done');

          console.log(sliderLocation);
        }
      });
    }
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
    move_classes('backwards');
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
    move_classes('forward');
  });
});

function move_classes(moveDirection) {
  var previous_slide = jQuery('.previous_slide');
  var current_slide = jQuery('.current_slide');
  var next_slide = jQuery('.next_slide');
  var slides = [previous_slide, current_slide, next_slide];
  var slidesClasses = ['previous_slide', 'current_slide', 'next_slide'];

  i = 0;
  slides.forEach(function(arrayValue) {
    if (moveDirection == 'forward') {
      var slideToMove = arrayValue.next();
      if (!slideToMove.length) {
        slideToMove = arrayValue.parent().find('div:first');
      }
    } else if (moveDirection == 'backwards') {
      var slideToMove = arrayValue.prev();
      if (!slideToMove.length) {
        slideToMove = arrayValue.parent().find('div:last-child');
      }
    }
    // console.log(slideToMove);
    // console.log(arrayValue);

    slideToMove.addClass(slidesClasses[i]);
    arrayValue.removeClass(slidesClasses[i]);
    i++;
  });
}
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider .slides_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  perspective: 1200px;
}

#slider .slides_container div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* width: 750px;
        height: 450px; */
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 7px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Coverflow css */

.previous_slide {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -300px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(50deg);
  z-index: 0;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

.current_slide {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 1;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

.next_slide {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -300px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-50deg);
  z-index: 0;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">
    <p>></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev">
    <p><</p>
  </a>
  <div class="slides_container">
    <div style="background-color: red">Last Slide Duplicate</div>
    <div style="background-color: green">1</div>
    <div style="background-color: blue">2</div>
    <div style="background-color: orange">3</div>
    <div style="background-color: grey">4</div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow">First Slide Duplicate</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JostiFrank/ecr2bzsL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the initial value of your animated property. Since you are not animating a simple css numeric value there is no reference for the start of `now` in your `step`function of your animation. To set that value simply set that value on the object with

```
$('#slider .slides_container')[0].sliderLocation = -slideWidth;
```

and then animate that new property

```
$('#slider .slides_container').animate({
    sliderLocation: sliderLocation
} ...
```

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slides_container div:first').addClass('previous_slide');
  $('.slides_container div:nth-child(2)').addClass('current_slide');
  $('.slides_container div:nth-child(3)').addClass('next_slide');
});

var options = {
  autoplay: 0000, //delay between transitions in milliseconds; 0 or lower is no autoplay
  sliderTransitionSpeed: 1200, //speed of the animation when changing slides
  transitionAnimation: '',
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (options.autoplay > 0) {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, options.autoplay);
  }
  
  if (options.transitionAnimation == 'slider') {
    jQuery('#slider').addClass('slider');
  } else if (options.transitionAnimation == 'coverflow') {
    jQuery('#slider').addClass('coverflow');
  } else {
    jQuery('#slider').addClass('slider');
  }

  var slideCount = $('#slider .slides_container div').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider .slides_container div').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider .slides_container div').height();
  var sliderContainerWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
  $('#slider .slides_container')[0].sliderLocation = -slideWidth;
  $('#slider .slides_container').css({
    transform: "translate3d(" + -slideWidth + "px, 0px, 0px)"
  });

  $('#slider .slides_container div').css("line-height", slideHeight + "px");

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider .slides_container').css({
    width: sliderContainerWidth
  });
  
  $('#slider .slides_container').css({
    "transform": "translate3d( px, 0px, 0px)"
  });
  
  // , marginLeft: - slideWidth
  // $('#slider .slides_container div:last-child').prependTo('#slider .slides_container');

  var sliderLocation = -slideWidth;
  var maxLocationRight = slideCount * -slideWidth + slideWidth;
  console.log(maxLocationRight);
  console.log(sliderLocation);

  function moveLeft() {
    sliderLocation += slideWidth;
    if (sliderLocation == 0) {
      console.log("begin");
    }
    $('#slider .slides_container').animate({
      sliderLocation: sliderLocation
    }, {
      step: function(now, fx) {
        $(this).css({
          "transform": "translate3d(" + now + "px, 0px, 0px)"
        });
      },
      duration: options.sliderTransitionSpeed,
      complete: function() {
        console.log('Animation is done');
        console.log(sliderLocation);
      }
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    if (sliderLocation == maxLocationRight) {
      $('#slider .slides_container').css({
        transform: "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"
      });
      sliderLocation = 0;

      console.log(sliderLocation);
      console.log("end");
    } else {
      console.log("moveRight");
      sliderLocation -= slideWidth;

      $('#slider .slides_container').animate({
        sliderLocation: sliderLocation
      }, {
        step: function(now, fx) {
          $(this).css({
            "transform": "translate3d(" + now + "px, 0px, 0px)"
          });
        },
        duration: options.sliderTransitionSpeed,
        complete: function() {
          console.log('Animation is done');

          console.log(sliderLocation);
        }
      });
    }
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
    move_classes('backwards');
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
    move_classes('forward');
  });
});

function move_classes(moveDirection) {
  var previous_slide = jQuery('.previous_slide');
  var current_slide = jQuery('.current_slide');
  var next_slide = jQuery('.next_slide');
  var slides = [previous_slide, current_slide, next_slide];
  var slidesClasses = ['previous_slide', 'current_slide', 'next_slide'];

  i = 0;
  slides.forEach(function(arrayValue) {
    if (moveDirection == 'forward') {
      var slideToMove = arrayValue.next();
      if (!slideToMove.length) {
        slideToMove = arrayValue.parent().find('div:first');
      }
    } else if (moveDirection == 'backwards') {
      var slideToMove = arrayValue.prev();
      if (!slideToMove.length) {
        slideToMove = arrayValue.parent().find('div:last-child');
      }
    }
    // console.log(slideToMove);
    // console.log(arrayValue);

    slideToMove.addClass(slidesClasses[i]);
    arrayValue.removeClass(slidesClasses[i]);
    i++;
  });
}
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider .slides_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  perspective: 1200px;
}

#slider .slides_container div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* width: 750px;
        height: 450px; */
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 7px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Coverflow css */

.previous_slide {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -300px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(50deg);
  z-index: 0;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

.current_slide {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 1;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

.next_slide {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -300px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-50deg);
  z-index: 0;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">
    <p>></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev">
    <p><</p>
  </a>
  <div class="slides_container">
    <div style="background-color: red">Last Slide Duplicate</div>
    <div style="background-color: green">1</div>
    <div style="background-color: blue">2</div>
    <div style="background-color: orange">3</div>
    <div style="background-color: grey">4</div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow">First Slide Duplicate</div>
  </div>
</div>
```